# Is the following a subspace of $V= \{\sigma: A\to K\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be nonempty, $K$ a field, $V= \{\sigma: A \to K\}$.
>
> A) Show that $V$ with pointwise addition and pointwise scalar multiplication is a $K$-vectorspace.
>
> B) Let $a,b,c \in A$. Is $U=\{\sigma \in V : \sigma(a)\sigma(b) = \sigma(b)\sigma(c)\}$ a subspace of $V$?

This looks like a straight-forward exercise, but somehow my solution differs from the proposed solution. Could someone verify?

I have proven that $V$ is a vectorspace. (A)

(B) Now since $\sigma(b) \in K$ there exists a multiplicative inverse and the multiplication in $K$ is commutative $\sigma(a)\sigma(b) = \sigma(b)\sigma(c) \Leftrightarrow \sigma(a) = \sigma(c)$. *right?*

Then let $\phi, \psi \in U, \lambda, \mu \in K$ then I check if $\lambda \phi + \mu \psi \in U$.

I check the following
$$(\lambda \phi+\mu\psi)(a) = \lambda \phi(a)+\mu \psi(a) = \lambda \phi(c)+\mu \psi(c) = (\lambda\phi+\mu\psi)(c)$$

So $\lambda\phi+\mu \psi \in U$. And then $U\leqslant V$.

*However the course solutions say: if $a=c$ then $U\leqslant V$*

Have I made a mistake? (I have some doubts about $\sigma(b)$ as it could be zero, but then the identity $\sigma(a)\sigma(b) = \sigma(b)\sigma(c)$ is trivial?)

Comment: you can't say that multiplication in $K$ is commutative, your field is commutative ?

Comment: @Hamza Surprisingly (as I'm French) a field is commutative in English. So a field is not the exact translation of "un corps" in French.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: what's the exact translation of "un corps"? I had always thought it to be "field".

Comment: A division ring in English is the translation of "un corps" in French. A good tip to look for translation of math words is to look at Wikipedia in French and to go to "Lire dans une autre langue".

Comment: think you @mathcounterexamples.net for the comment (I studied mathematics in french too)  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doubt is good... $U$ is not a subspace of $V$.

Take $$\phi(x)= \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x=c\\ 
0 & \mbox{else}
\end{cases}$$ and $$\psi(x)= \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x=b\\ 
0 & \mbox{else}
\end{cases}$$ $\phi$ and $\psi$ belong to $U$. However, $\phi +\psi$ does not.